# Remove duplicates in array where first instance should be ignored and only use second instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In an array that has duplicates, I am trying to remove the first instance of duplicate from it and wanted to only use second instance of that duplicate in it.
say I have this array

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```

when I do this `const b = [...new Set(a)]`
my output will be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

But I need the order/output to be `['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']`
is there a why I can achieve this?

Comment: Second instance or last instance?  What would you expect from `['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']`?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat last instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a quick way to do this is to reverse the array, remove the duplicates, then reverse it back again :

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
const b = [...new Set(a.reverse())].reverse()

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great